# Meaning of "as if so gentle that you could not see" in a poem by Keats

Tags: conjunctions, phrase-meaning, poetry

[On a Picture of Leander](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Poetical_Works_of_John_Keats/On_a_Picture_of_Leander), by Keats:

> Come hither, all sweet maidens soberly,
>   Down-looking aye, and with a chasten'd light,
>   Hid in the fringes of your eyelids white,
>   And meekly let your fair hands joined be,
>   **As if so gentle that ye could not see**,
>   Untouch'd, a victim of your beauty bright,
>   Sinking away to his young spirit's night,
>   Sinking bewilder'd 'mid the dreary sea:
>   'Tis young Leander toiling to his death;
>   Nigh swooning, he doth purse his weary lips
>   For Hero's cheek, and smiles against her smile.
>   O horrid dream! see how his body dips
>   Dead-heavy; arms and shoulders gleam awhile:
>   He's gone; up bubbles all his amorous breath!

I don't understand this line - especially the conjunction "if". I cannot attach this "if" to anything. What is the condition for this "if"?

The only interpretation I came up with is "join your hands, as if, if you didn't join your hands, you couldn't see Leander sinking". It's a bit absurd. As if their hands, when joined, produce a piece of equipment (an electrical circuit or an antenna) that is able to resolve Leander sinking. And when their hands are unlocked, there is not enough scanning power.

Comment: I take it to mean 'As if [you were] so gentle that you could not see Leander sinking without feeling touched'.

Comment: @KateBunting I think you're right, the phrase breaks over the line ending  so that the whole phrase becomes "As if so gentle that you could not see untouched" which makes more sense of both the highlighted phrase and the otherwise dangling "Untouched". Well spotted!